# how to make a function that checks whole numbers in a sequence

Tags: r, sequence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if each element in a vector is integer or not in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113933/how-to-check-if-each-element-in-a-vector-is-integer-or-not-in-r)

How to make a function that checks whether a number is a whole number (such as -3, 2.0, 0,3, and 4.0000, but not 3.3, or 2.001)

Comment: Well, with floating point types, you will have to define what a whole number is because some whole numbers cannot be represented exactly by the usual IEEE binary FP types, eg: is 2.999999999999998 a whole number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113933/how-to-check-if-each-element-in-a-vector-is-integer-or-not-in-r

Comment: Technically whole numbers don't include negatives.

Comment: @MartinJames "some whole numbers cannot be represented exactly" along with your 2.999999999999998 example seems like it could be misleading to someone new to floating point. All integers smaller in magnitude than 9 007 199 254 740 992 can be represented exactly in an IEEE754 double. There is certainly no question about 3. The real problems start with the results of _computations_, e.g. determining whether `0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1` (which mathematically should equal 1) is an integer.

Answer (score 5):

Try typing in R:

```
?is.integer
```

You will go to this page:
[R is.integer() page](http://127.0.0.1:28552/library/base/html/integer.html)

At the bottom is a function that I believe you want:

```
is.wholenumber <-
    function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
is.wholenumber(1) # is TRUE
(x <- seq(1,5, by=0.5) )
is.wholenumber( x ) #-->  TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
```