# Cleaning up likert scale data: How to test whether data is consecutive in addition to some unrelated strings?

Tags: r, likert

I need to clean up data that was collected with a likert scale. It means that observations in my data are from people who chose one option from an ordinal scale, such as "*on a scale of 1-5, where 1 means awful and 5 means wonderful, how would you rate your liking of eggplants?*"

Thus, a typical dataset will look like

```r
library(tibble)

set.seed(123)
df_a <- 
  tibble(name = c("clara", "john", "michelle", "dan", 'timothy', "cindy", "george", "monica", "david", "rebecca"),
       response = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE))

   name     response
   <chr>       <int>
 1 clara           3
 2 john            3
 3 michelle        2
 4 dan             2
 5 timothy         3
 6 cindy           5
 7 george          4
 8 monica          1
 9 david           2
10 rebecca         3
```

**My task is to test whether the data is indeed likert scale**, meaning that (1) values are integers, and (2) if we summarize the unique values, they are consecutive.

1. Testing whether all are integers can be done by

```r
all((df_a$response - round(df_a$response)) == 0) ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114038/6105259

[1] TRUE
```

2. Testing whether unique values are consecutive [actually I don't know how to do this, but my problem doesn't end here].

### My real problem is that likert scale could have different variations and that other strings might show in the data, adding noise.

- valid likert scale could span different ranges, for example either 1-5, or 0-3, or 1-10 etc.
- many times there will be *additional* strings such as "irrelevant", "I don't know", "I don't think so", "not applicable to me", and so on. I cannot anticipate which such additional strings will be present in the data, if any at all.

Under such circumstances, I need to detect whether my data is essentially likely to be from "likert scale".

Criteria to decide data *is* likert scale:

1. numeric values are integers.
2. when we take the unique values, they are consecutive (in the sense that `sort(unique(df_a$response))` returns `1 2 3 4 5`. If it had returned `1 3 4 5` then it would have failed the "consecutiveness" criteria)
3. the smallest value in the range is either `0` or `1`
4. the greatest value is `10`.
5. noise strings that *aren't* numeric (such as "I don't know", "abcd34", "irrelevant") account for less than 50% of the data

---

**Below are 4 examples to demonstrate possible types of data and what I expect should happen when testing them for whether they're "likert" or not**

In the examples I use `stringi::stri_rand_strings` to simulate the "noise" strings (e.g., "I don't know", "irrelevant", and other examples I gave above)

---

### Example 1 -- testing for "is likert scale" should return `TRUE`

```r
library(stringi)

set.seed(19)
val_begin <- sample(0:1, 1)
val_end <- sample(3:10, 1)
my_seq <- seq(from = val_begin, to = val_end)
additional_strings <- stri_rand_strings(n = 2, length = 5, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]")

vec_example_1 <- sample(c(my_seq, additional_strings), size = 100 , replace = TRUE)
```

```r
barplot(prop.table(table(vec_example_1)), main = "vec example 1)
```

[image: vec_example_1]

### Example 2 -- testing for "is likert scale" should return `FALSE`

In the following data, numbers are not consecutive

```r
set.seed(19)
my_seq_2 <- sort(c(seq(0,4), seq(7, 9)))
additional_strings_2 <- stri_rand_strings(n = 2, length = 5, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]")
vec_example_2 <- sample(c(my_seq_2, additional_strings_2), size = 100 , replace = TRUE)
```

```r
barplot(prop.table(table(vec_example_2)), main = "vec example 2)
```

[image: vec_example_2]

### Example 3 -- testing for "is likert scale" should return `FALSE`

In the following data, the "additional strings" account for more than 50% of data, making it unlikely that the core of data is likert scale

```r
set.seed(19)
vec_example_3 <- sample(c(rep(additional_strings, 70), sample(my_seq, 30, replace = T))) 
barplot(prop.table(table(vec_example_3)), main = "vec example 3")
```

[image: vec_example_3]

### Example 4 -- testing for "is likert scale" should return `FALSE`

Just random numbers and strings, no reason to believe this is a likert scale, even if it happens to be unique and consecutive, but 1 -> 30 is simply unlikely to be likert.

```r
set.seed(19)
vec_example_4 <- sample(c(1:30, additional_strings), 1000, replace = T) 
barplot(prop.table(table(vec_example_4)), main = "vec example 4")
```

[image: vec_example_4]

---

### What I'm asking

I assume that a full solution would be pretty lengthy, so maybe it's too much to ask from people here. So I will be happy for even just tips, a general approach, or ideas how to tackle this.

Comment: `anyDuplicated(rle(x$values) == 0` will be TRUE if every unique value is in a single run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to identify if the vector follows the rules that we are looking for.

```
is_likert <- function(x) {
  only_numbers <- sort(as.numeric(unique(grep('^\\d+$', x, value = TRUE))))
  all_integers <- all(only_numbers %% 1 == 0)
  are_consecutive <- all(diff(only_numbers) == 1)
  ratio_of_numbers <- mean(grepl('^\\d+$', x))
  max_num <- max(only_numbers)
  min_num <- min(only_numbers)

  all_integers && are_consecutive && ratio_of_numbers > 0.5 && 
  max_num <= 10 && min_num <= 1
}

is_likert(vec_example_1)
#[1] TRUE
is_likert(vec_example_2)
#[1] FALSE
is_likert(vec_example_3)
#[1] FALSE
is_likert(vec_example_4)
#[1] FALSE
```

I hope the variable names are clear enough to demonstrate what they are doing.